# Effective scripting option to Automate MKS Integrity

Tags: python, perl, ui-automation, mks, mks-integrity

I want to create one script that will open the Windows application to perform some task.

Application is PTC integrity,

I want to write a script that would open the items ( via unique Item ID ) and make changes in one of it's attribute's value and save it.

Tasks that my script should do:

```
1. Open the application.
2. Open the document using ID.
3. Open the Item via provided ID.
4. Assign a new value to the attribute provided by the script.
```

I would like to know which scripting language should I use to get the above task done. Can it be done via VBA or Perl or Python etc.
Since I'm new I'm open for good suggestions.

NOTE : I've worked on AutoIT before. So, Let me know if it can be of any use for PTC Integrity Automation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which script is better for automation of PTC Integrity application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168596/which-script-is-better-for-automation-of-ptc-integrity-application)

Comment: I've read that question Mr @Corion ..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try Python to automate different processes in PTC integrity tool.You can use CLI commands for all your operations.Run those CLI commands from Python using subprocess method. Get your output in your preferable format.

You can do multiple PTC options like create,edit,delete of documents and items.You can also do some difficult options with this.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the mentioned languages can send keystrokes to other Windows applications, so automating that program using any of them should work:

- [AutoIt Send()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm)
- [Perl Win32::GuiTest SendKeys()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GuiTest)
- [Python win32com.SendKeys()](https://win32com.goermezer.de/microsoft/windows/controlling-applications-via-sendkeys.html)
- [VBA SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement)

Comment: VBA SendKeys was very effective solution for my task. Let me know if there is any update in the above list that you've provided. The list rocks!